# Distribution of a Brownian bridge

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I am self studying some stochastic calculus material and come across this question to show that the distribution of $P(W(s)\in dy|W(t)=x)$ with $W(0)=0$ is normal with mean $\frac{s}{t}W(t)$ and variance $s(t-s)$.

So I use: $P(W(s)\in dy|W(t)=x)=\frac{P(W(s)\in dy)P(W(t)\in dx|W(s)=y)}{P(W(t)\in dx)}$

In addition we know that: $P(W(t)\in dx|W(s)=y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(t-s)}}\exp\{-\frac{(x-y)^{2}}{2(t-s)}\}dx$

Hence, \begin{align*}
P(W(s)\in dy|W(t)=s) & =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}}\exp\{-\frac{y^{2}}{2s}\}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(t-s)}}\exp\{-\frac{(x-y)^{2}}{2(t-s)}\}\times\sqrt{2\pi t}\exp\{\frac{x^{2}}{2t}\}\\
 & =\frac{t}{\sqrt{2\pi ts(t-s)}}\exp\{-\frac{(yt-sx)^{2}}{2ts(t-s)}\}
\end{align*}

Now I can see that the mean can be shifted to be $\frac{s}{t}W(t)$ but how do I see that the variance is $s(t-s)$ from this expression ?

Thanks

Comment: $$\frac{t}{\sqrt{2\pi ts(t-s)}}\exp\left(-\frac{(yt-sx)^{2}}{2ts(t-s)}\right)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^{2}}}\exp\left(-\frac{(y-sx/t)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}\right)\qquad\sigma^{2}=\frac{s(t-s)}{t}$$